# Regex, everything between 2 html tags vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i'm trying to get some information of a webpage via regex on visual basic 2010

it's something like this:

```
<SPAN CLASS="clear"></SPAN>
<h2> blabla </h2>
<h2> blabla </h2>
<b> blabla </b>

etc etc

<SPAN CLASS="clear"></SPAN>
```

what i want is everything between the 2 
also the h2 tags and every other html tag that exists.

is this possible?

i've already tried (.*?) and .* and \w* but it doesn't return anything...

Comment: I think you don't need to work with RegEx, but use a XMlReader in your  code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably best to use an XML parser for that, but I'm assuming it's a one-off scrape or similar.

If I understand you correctly, this should get all the data between the tags:

```
Dim regex As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<.*?>", RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim result As String = regex.Replace(yourHtml, String.Empty)
```

You could use this to get just the H2 tags and data:

```
Dim regex As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<\s*h2[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*h2>", RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim results As New Text.StringBuilder
For Each m As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In regex.Matches(yourHtml)
    results.Append(m.Value)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

**alundy** already have good answer, yet you can try this one too.

```
Dim findtext2 As String = "(?<=<h2>)(.*?)(?=</h2>)"
Dim myregex2 As String = TextBox1.Text 'Your HTML code
Dim doregex2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex2, findtext2)
Dim matches2 As String = ""
For Each match2 As Match In doregex2
    matches2 = matches2 + match2.ToString + Environment.NewLine
Next
MsgBox(matches2) 'Results
```

Don't forget `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

Above code is getting all information between 2 strings, in this case - `<h2>` and `</h2>`. You can use whatever you want (it doesn't need to be tag, not even html).