# Regex to get text between two strings

Tags: regex, vb.net, .net-4.0

I want to get dynamic <strike>six</strike> seven-digit numbers as shown below:

```
id="tid_3660328">
```

and append them to the end of TextBox1.

---

In other words, I want to get the number: 3660328

From between: id="tid_

and: ">

---

My question is how I could do this in VB.NET. My first thought was "regex", which is a topic I have zero experience on. I appreciate the help.

Note: I was thinking I could use the code here but with my own regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9332731

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has everything you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11161232/128221

Comment: Is the number *always* six digits?  For instance, in your example, it's seven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good place for using RegEx.

If you only want to find numbers that are exactly seven digits you could use this RegEx pattern:

```
id="tid_(\d{7})">
```

Or, if you don't care how many digits it is, you could use this pattern:

```
id="tid_(\d+)">
```

Here's what the pattern means:

- `id="tid_` - Matching strings must begin with this text
- `(...)` - Creates a group so that we can later access the value of just this part of the match.
- `\d` - Any numeric digit character
- `{7}` - Seven numeric characters in a row
- `">` - Matching strings must end with this text

In the second pattern, the `+`, which replaces the `{7}` just means one-or-more instead of exactly seven.

In VB.NET, you can search an input string using a RegEx pattern, like this:

```
Public Function FindNumbers(input As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim numbers As New List(Of String)()
    Dim pattern As String = "id=""tid_(\d{7})"">"
    For Each i As Match In Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
        numbers.Add(i.Groups(1).Value)
    Next
    Return numbers
End Function
```

Notice that in the string literal in VB, you have to escape the quotation marks by doubling them.  You'll also notice that, instead of using `i.Value`, we are using `i.Groups(1).Value`.  The reason is that `i.Value` will equal the entire matched string (e.g. `id="tid_3660328">`), whereas group 1 will equal just the number part (e.g. `3660328`).

### Update

To answer your question below, to call this function and output it to a `TextBox`, you could do something like this:

```
Dim numbers As List(Of String) = FindNumbers("id=""tid_3660328"">")
Text1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers.ToArray())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. How would I call this function and export the results to a TextBox?

Comment: @KelvinZhang I updated my answer to show how you could do that.

Comment: Finally, I wanted to apply your code to a new regex: <input type="hidden" name="my_post_key" value="GET HERE" /> ------ I've tried 'Dim postpattern As String = "<input type=""hidden"" name=""my_post_key"" value=""(\S+)"" />"' without success (notice I've changed 'pattern' to 'postpattern' to prevent ambiguity). Is there anything wrong with my regex?

Comment: The `<` character has special meaning to RegEx, so you need to escape it with a \ character.  (e.g. `pattern = "\<blah>"`)  It doesn't hurt to escape the closing pointy bracket too.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=tid_).*?(?=\"\>)
```

Explanation:

- (?<=tid_) : Match the Prefix tid_ but exclude it from the capture
- .*? : Any Character, any number of repetitions, as few as possible
- (?=\">) : Match the suffix "> but exclude it from the capture

Comment: So I've done some research to understand the Regex:

So () are the groups with the criteria and ".*?" is the wildcard, right?

What does "?<=" and "?=" do then?

Comment: Added the explanation to the above answer. Let me know if you need more information. In addition you could use a tool like expresso to construct new regexes and understand existing regexes.

Comment: Does your regex function in a different way from Steven's, or do they do the same thing? If it's the latter, I'll be slightly confused.

Comment: Stevan's regex pattern will also capture the prefix tid_( and )">