# Replace text between custome tags

Tags: regex

sample of a user entered text paragraph is below.  Users can insert a video link under [vinsert]......[/vinsert] tags. I wanted to extract the id number from inner text and replace all text from start to end of the tag so a video will display. Users can insert one or more inserts.

===================================

Dim MyStr2 As String = "

Sample text [vinsert]http://www.example.com/video/34760/mytestvideo.aspx[/vinsert]

Sample text sample text

"

[vinsert]http://www.example.com/video/66779/testing.aspx[/vinsert]     -> vidid => 666779 or 34760 is a variable  which I need to extract  and make a database call to find the video filename.

Dim filename As string

Select filename from myvideotable where id = vidid

I wanted to replace the [vinsert]......[/vinsert] to become  the text as below.

```
<div class="myClass"><iframe width="560" height="315"  src="//www.example.com/embed/<%= filename%>"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

I tried to use this without success: [Regex, everything between 2 html tags vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331001/regex-everything-between-2-html-tags-vb-net) Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use lookahead and look behind. This regex pattern should work

```
  (?<=}\[vinsert\]).*(?=\[/vinsert\])
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks. I use this code line with the pattern:  Dim regex As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("?<=}\[peoplecinema\]).*(?=\[/peoplecinema\]")
        Dim results As New Text.StringBuilder
        For Each m As Text.RegularExpressions.Match In Regex.Matches(MyStr2)
            results.Append(m.Value)
        Next